# Table operation .net library

Tags: .net, sorting, memory, filtering

In some web pages that I have, I must join some datatables in memory and then use the result as a datasource for a gridview. This in-memory join is the only solution, and I have written a method that takes care of it.

I was wondering if there is any library out there that can do such things and other table operations, like ordering and filtering.  I am aware of dataview sorting and the select method on a datatable, but I am looking for something that returns a datatable as result.

Besides I am not convinced that the code I have written is the best possible from a performance point-of-view so I would like to at least compare it with a third party implementation. Since the application has to work on .Net 2.0, Linq is not an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a datatable?
A gridview will take a dataview without complaint.

If your on .NET 3.5 then Linq's definately your man.